# Unable to call function with self

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple code snippet here, but unable to run the code

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def functiona(self, a):
        b = a+0
        print(b)

    def functionb(self):
        a = 5
        self.functiona(a)

test.functionb('abc')
```

It errors out with "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'functiona'" Unable to call it with self. However, if I provide test.functiona(a) it works fine.

Few of other code samples works with self.function, how to solve this issue

Comment: `functionb` is an instance method. You're supposed to create an instance of your class use that to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.functionb('abc')` is a function call on the class, not on an instance.

I suppose it works if you do `test().functionb('abc')`?

The difference is:

- In your case, you call the function object on the class. As it is not a staticmethod or classmethod, it is called with `self = 'abc'`, a string. This string hasn't a method `functiona()`.
- In my case, the call operates on a class instance. Here, `self` is set to the instance you just created – and you get an error because it doesn't know where to pass the `'abc'`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the decorator `@classmethod` and then call it like you did

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def functiona(self, a):
        b = a+0
        print(b)
    @classmethod
    def functionb(self):
        a = 5
        self.functiona(a)
```

```sh
>>> test.functiona(1001)
>>> 1001
>>> test.functionb()
>>> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in the call `test.functionb('abc')`. You are not using object of the class to call the method. So, the `self` parameter is not passed. 
Python considers, the first parameter to be self, and you passed `'abc'` which is a string.

Use it like `test().functionb('abc')` , then the default first argument becomes the object of `test` - like `functionb(test_ob, 'abc')`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in the call test.functionb('abc'). You are not using object of the class to call the method. So, the self parameter is not passed. Python considers, the first parameter to be self, and you passed 'abc' which is a string.

Use it like test().functionb('abc') , then the default first argument becomes the object of test - like functionb(test_ob, 'abc').